# Where are the customer Jobs stored in QuickBooks and how to retrieve them using SDK?

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks

I had created a Customer in QuickBooks to which I have added a Job. I want to retrieve that Job or say I want to retrieve all the Jobs of a customer. How do I do that.

I am able to retrieve the customer details using this code,

ICustomerQuery customerQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerQueryRq();

But I am having problems in getting the Job details of that Customer. How do I do it using SDK in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jobs in QuickBooks are the exact same thing as Customers. Jobs are simply Customers with a parent Customer assigned.

You query them the exact same way you query Customers.